# SKLabelNode does not change fontColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, swift

I have a SKLabelNode added in my SKScene and it's color is black. But somewhere in the code I am doing

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            var keysArr = playerLabels.allKeys
            for k in keysArr {

                var playerLabel = k as SKLabelNode

                if CGRectContainsPoint(playerLabel.frame, location) {

                    selectedPlayer = playerLabels.objectForKey(playerLabel) as AvailablePlayer

                    playerLabel.fontColor = UIColor.redColor()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and it does not change the label node color. I have to do

```
playerLabel.removeFromParent()                  
self.addChild(playerLabel)
```

so that the color change would take effect. This looks like a hack to me and I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if there is another way to do this.

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you setting the font color?

Comment: i made an edit. it's inside the touchesBegan function.

Comment: You can only do this from within the update: method.

Comment: Tried doing it in an update and it still does not work :(

Comment: I am seeing the same problem, but the hack doesn't work for me :(. Have you found out more?

Comment: I am overlaying a SpriteKit on a SceneKit and find I have to do something, like a null action, on the Scene before the Sprite updates.

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I do something with the scene like a null action the sprite updates, e.g.:

```
final class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    /// The view controller for the main scene (self!)
    private(set) static var viewController: MainViewController!

    private var mainNode: SCNNode!

    private var uiAction: SCNAction!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        // Retrieve and store the main node
        mainNode = main.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ship", recursively: true)!

        // Animate the UI (needed to allow buttons to respond - probably an iOS bug :( )
        uiAction = SCNAction.repeatAction((SCNAction.rotateByX(0, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)), count: 1)

        // Give other objects access to this view controller
        MainViewController.viewController = self
    }

    ...

    /// Force the update the UI by doing a nothing animation (probably an iOS 8 bug :( )
    func updateUI() {
        mainNode.runAction(uiAction)
    }

}
```

I then call updateUI every time I modify a sprite, e.g.:

```
MainViewController.viewController.updateUI()
```

Not ideal since you have to manually call updateUI, but it is the best I have come up with :(